# How to use background image in react bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, styling, reactstrap

I'm new to react `boostrap` and I'm confused how can I set the background image on a page here is my `app.js`. I tried  writing some code in return `<div>`.

In my button I just write the `className` and it's not working in the case of background image.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function App() {


  return (
    <div style={{ 
      backgroundImage: `url("https://via.placeholder.com/500")` 
    }}>
       <Navbar user={user} setUser={setUser} />
       <main>
        <Routes>

          <Route exact  path="/airlines" element={<><Search search={search} onSearchChange={setSearch} /><Airlines  /></>} />
           
          <Route exact  path="/myprofile" element={<><MyProfile myReviewsArray={myReviewsArray} setMyReviewsArray={setMyReviewsArray}  user={user}   /></>}/>
          

          <Route exact  path="/airlines/:id" element={<Reviews reviews={reviews} setReviews={setReviews}  onDeleteReview={handleDeleteReview}   />} />
           
          <Route path="/airlines/:id/reviews/new" element={ <AddreviewForm onAddReview={handleAddReviews} user={user}/>} />
        
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home user={user}/>} />
        
        </Routes>
      </main>

  </div>
  );
  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you provide codesandbox link if possible?

Comment: it has nothing to do either wit react-bootstrap nor with bootstrap itself.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with react-bootstrap or bootstrap itself. Your inline-style is for example one way to do so, and it is correct. When I copy paste your code, I see the placeholder-image:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url("https://via.placeholder.com/500")`,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100vh"
      }}
    ></div>
  );
}
```

Most propably, you didn't set the hight of the div so you didn't see the image.

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-lake-n042kx?file=/src/App.js